# AFrame Physics Impulse is not at center

Tags: physics, aframe, cannon.js

Very simply I want to shoot a cube straight up and have it land flat, not spinning as it goes. I would also like it to reliably end up in the same position if possible always when the same force vector is applied.... But that might be a cannon issue.

http://codepen.io/msj121/pen/zKOvPW

```
<a-scene physics>
    <!-- Camera -->
    <a-entity camera universal-controls position="0 1 0"></a-entity>

    <!-- Floor -->
    <a-grid static-body position="0 0 0"></a-grid>

    <!-- <a-sphere position="0 1 0.5" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#000000"></a-sphere>
    <a-sphere position="0 1 -0.5" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#000000"></a-sphere> -->
  <!-- Immovable box -->
  <!-- <a-sphere static-body position="0 2 -3" width="3" height="1" depth="1"></a-sphere> -->

  <!-- Dynamic box -->
  <a-entity geometry="box" id="cannon" src="/images/earth.jpg" dynamic-body position="0 1 -3" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#33AA33"></a-entity>

    <!-- Dynamic box -->
    <!-- <a-box dynamic-body position="0 1 -1" width="1" height="1" depth="1" color="#000000"></a-box> -->
  </a-scene>
  <div class="card card-block" style="position:absolute;left:0px;bottom:0px;width:250px;background-color:white;z-index:999">
    <h3 class="card-title">Forces:</h3>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-7 col-form-label">X Direction:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0" id="x">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-7 col-form-label">Y Direction:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="20" id="y">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group row">
      <label for="example-text-input" class="col-xs-7 col-form-label">Z Direction:</label>
      <div class="col-xs-5">
        <input class="form-control" type="text" value="0" id="z">
      </div>
    </div>
    <a id="impulseButton" class="btn btn-success" style="float:right;color:white" >Apply Force</a>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#impulseButton").on("click",function(){
        applyImpulse();
      });

      function applyImpulse(){
        var x = $("#x").val();
        var y = $("#y").val();
        var z = $("#z").val();
        if(x>=0 && y>=0 && z>=0){
          var el = $('#cannon')[0];
          console.log(new CANNON.Vec3(x,y,z));
          console.log(new CANNON.Vec3().copy(el.body.position));
          console.log(new CANNON.Vec3().copy(el.object3D.position));
          el.body.applyImpulse(
            /* impulse */        new CANNON.Vec3(x,y,z),
            /* world position */ new CANNON.Vec3().copy(el.body.position)
          );
        }
        else{
          alert("Values must be greater or equal to 0")
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just simulation noise, but you can constrain rotation using [CANNON.Body methods](http://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/docs/classes/Body.html):

```
el.body.fixedRotation = true;
el.body.updateMassProperties();
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked perfectly! Do you know will cannon.js be reliable to have the same physics results each simulation? Seems like not... Any experience with that?

Comment: I don't see `Math.random()` used in its main codebase. So it might be deterministic if you control the clock speed / make sure step sizes are always the same. My code [uses the framerate to time physics](https://github.com/donmccurdy/aframe-extras/blob/v2.3.0/src/physics/system/physics.js#L83), which behaves well but could allow variation.

Comment: What would be neat is if the simulation runs totally independent of rendering, simply drawing the scene when available but calculating based off of actual time etc... not steps in animation. This would help allow simulations to be identical. Nevertheless, it is a great library and thank you for developing it. Perhaps most people don't need things to behave the same each time.

Comment: Unfortunately the simulations still wouldn't be deterministic using actual time, since `setInterval` is very approximate. To get real guarantees you'd need to use a fixed time on each step (say, 10ms) even if 40ms have actually passed, and that means objects move slower or faster than they should. So, I'm not sure how to have both realistic timing and deterministic behavior. Would certainly be glad to support that if there's a way.

Comment: Sadly, your right. I think it is an issue in cannon.js itself the way it is coded. It should keep track of the real time by using Date() and updating to the right frame based off of draw events, no matter the system. Assuming you have good frame rate (even if it isn't constant) you can always get the same simulation since your using actual time.